# C# mTLS authentication with gRPC

Tags: c#, .net, azure-appservice, mtls, grpc-c#

I am trying to configure mTLS authentication for my gRPC application. The application is written in .net 6 and deployed on Azure app service (linux).

**App service configuration:**

Application Settings:

- HTTP20_ONLY_PORT - here is port for gRPC

General Settings:

- Http Version = 2.0
- HTTP 2.0 Proxy = On
- Client certificate mode = Ignore (i can call gRPC from my client), everything else I get an exception.

**gRPC app configuration looks like:**

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
   options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(httpsOptions =>
   {
      //httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = certificate;
      httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
   });
}
    
builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
{
   options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
   options.Interceptors.Add<AuthenticationInterceptor>(); // interceptor contains only logging
});
```

If I change configuration of ClientCertificateMode in code to something else, it's working but HttpContext has no client certificate.

**Here is my client:**

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("client.crt", "pwd");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("app-service-url", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    HttpHandler = handler,
});
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
```

**Self-signed certificates:**

```
#CA
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out rootCA.key -passout pass:<pwd> 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out rootCA.crt -passin pass:<pwd> -subj "//CN=MyRootCA"


#Server
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out server.key -passout pass:<pwd> 4096
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -passin pass:<pwd> -subj "//CN=app-service-url"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -sha256 -passin pass:<pwd>
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:<pwd> -passout pass:<pwd> -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt

#Client
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out client.key -passout pass:<pwd> 4096
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr -passin pass:<pwd> -subj "//CN=Client"
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 365 -sha256 -passin pass:<pwd>
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:<pwd> -passout pass:<pwd> -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt
```

I have installed client certificate on local machine, deployed server certificate to app service. This certificate, I have tried to directly set within ConfigureHttpsDefaults, but it was not working (same exception).

Also, I have tried to add configuration for forwarding headers, but unsuccessfully.
It looks like the main problem is with app service. If Client certificate mode (app service) has any values except ignore, it's not working and I am getting this exception:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error
> starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not
> be established, see inner exception. AuthenticationException:
> Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert:
> 'ProtocolVersion'. Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected
> or badly formatted.",
> DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception.  --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication
> failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'.
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean
> isApm)    at
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---

Please do you have some hints what I could to try next?

**UPDATE**
TLS is set to 1.2.
My OS is Win 11.

If I update client to use tls12:

```
handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

then I get this exception:

> Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see
> inner exception. AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see
> inner exception. Win32Exception: The function requested is not
> supported

If I tried to load app service through chrome, popup with selecting certificates is displayed and no exception or error is displayed in chrome. So maybe something with my OS or client configuration?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/HowTo/gRPC/use_gRPC_with_dotnet.md?

Comment: yes, it's case when Client certificate mode is set to Ignore and it's working. But after changing to Allow or Required, it stops to work.

Comment: Check the TLS version: Make sure that the TLS version being used by your application is supported by Azure App Service. Azure App Service supports TLS 1.2, so if your application is using an older version of TLS, it may not be able to establish a secure connection. You can try setting the SslProtocols property on the HttpClientHandler to SslProtocols.Tls12 to force the use of TLS 1.2.

Comment: I'd suggest trying with the same certificates with Grpc.Core to see if the certificates work. Also, you could try to run Grpc.Core client against grpc-dotnet server to narrow down what could be wrong.  Potentially, you could also use wireshark to help you diagnose what went wrong with the handshake (perhaps it's going to be something obvious).

Comment: From your example it looks like you're getting "protocol_version" TLS alert: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/ssl-tls-alert-protocol-and-the-alert-codes/ba-p/377132 which has description "The protocol version the client attempted to negotiate is recognized, but not supported. For example, old protocol versions might be avoided for security reasons. This message is always fatal.". So you should really double check on TLS versions that are being used.